# Iterating with padding

Tags: python, loops, generator

I want to make a function that can iterate through anything (n specified times) put in the parameter and generate with padding.

So lets say I have this function:

```
def generate_with_padding(tobeiterated, n, pad = None):
     ...
```

If I call using a string lets say: `generate_with_padding('abcdefg', 10, '?')`

I would like it to return:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
?
?
?
```

I don't want to use indexing because I want to iterate through generators too. How can I approach this? Maybe I can use next()?

Comment: Are you looking for function that returns a generator?

Comment: @g.d.d.c Preferably not using built in modules.

Comment: Why on earth don't you want to use a built-in?

Comment: Maybe he wants to know how he could implement it himself? If the question is for self-education?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just keeping a count inside a `foreach` loop?
I am not sure if this violates your constraint about "using indices", but it does achieve the behavior you desire, and it works with generators.

```
def generate_with_padding(tobeiterated, n, pad = None):
     count = 0
     for x in tobeiterated:
         count = count + 1
         yield x
     for _ in xrange(n - count):
         yield pad
```

For example, the following generates the output you want:

```
for i in generate_with_padding('abcdefg', 10, '?'):
   print i
```

Comment: I would avoid using `_` as a variable name.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but I use it when I want to make the point that the variable is unused and doesn't matter. See  this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python

Answer (score 2):

`itertools` is the best answer. You can do it like this

```
from itertools import repeat, chain, islice

def generate_with_padding(tobeiterated, n, pad = None):
    return islice(chain(tobeiterated, repeat(pad)), n)
```

**Few tests**

```
def generator():
    for i in xrange(1, 6):
        yield i

print list(generate_with_padding("abcd", 10, "?"))
print list(generate_with_padding([1, 2], 5))
print list(generate_with_padding(generator(), 10, 0))
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']
[1, 2, None, None, None]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Note:** If you want the output to be a list, instead of an iterator, you can replace `return` statement, like this

```
return list(islice(chain(tobeiterated, repeat(pad)), n))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already built into the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and thus works with all iterables, including generators:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = "abcdefg"
>>> [item for item, index in itertools.izip_longest(a, xrange(10), fillvalue="?")]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '?', '?', '?']
```

If you use `()` instead of `[]`, you get a generator instead of a list (which I used here for visualization).

Comment: Interesting, but I think I have to prefer @thefourtheye's approach - it seems like a more direct statement of the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ljust` or `rjust` based on your padding orientation. Basic syntax is:

```
str="Padding String";
s= str.ljust(20,'?');
l=list(s)
print(l)
```

Output: `['P', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '?', '?',
 '?', '?', '?', '?']`

You can pass your parameters to `ljust` function. This is out of box, you don't need to import anything.

Comment: I think question has been asked for String :)

Comment: Look at the default parameter specified in the question :)